# Converting Data Frame entry to float in Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, data-science

I'm trying to save the values from populatioEst column in float variables using Python3 & Pandas,
I have the following table:

| Name | populationEst |
| --- | --- |
| Amsterdam | 872757 |
| Netherlands | 17407585 |

I have tried to separate both values as following,

```
populationAM = pops['populationEst'][pops.Name == 'Amsterdam']
populationNL = pops['populationEst'][pops.Name == 'Netherlands']
```

However when I try to print out the value,`print(populationAM)`, I get this output

```
0    872757
Name: PopulationEstimate2020-01-01, dtype: int64
```

and I think that populationAM & populationNL are not int values, because Whenever I try to run some arithmetic operation on them I do not get the desired value.

For example, I have tried to calculate the fraction of the populationAM against populationNL using this formula

```
frac = populationAM.astype(float) * 100 / populationNL.astype(float)
```

and I did not get the desired output that should be `5,013659276` but I have got this one:

```
0 Nan
1 Nan
Name: PopulationEst, dtype: float64
```

Can Anybody tell where am I going wrong here or how can I save these values in simple float variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what are you looking for?

```py
populationAM = pops.loc[pops.Name == 'Amsterdam', 'populationEst'].iloc[0]
populationNL = pops.loc[pops.Name == 'Netherlands', 'populationEst'].iloc[0]
frac = populationAM * 100 / populationNL
```

The value of `frac` here is 5.013659275539944, while `populationAM` and `populationNL` are the integers corresponding to the respective populations (as you can see, the type of these variables is not a problem to compute the correct value of `frac`). In your code, the issue is that `populationAM` and `populationNL` are pandas Series, instead of integers; `iloc[0]` retrieves the value in the first position of the series.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?:

```
populationAM = pops[pops['pops.Name'] == 'Amsterdam']['populationEst']
populationNL = pops[pops['pops.Name'] == 'Netherlands']['populationEst']
```

Comment: No that will separate the whole row actually, this is like saying:
 `SELECT * FROM pops WHERE pops.Name == Amsterdam, `

What I have done is more like: 
`SELECT populationEst FROM pops WHERE pops.Name == Amsterdam`

because pops['populationEst'] on its own is a sub dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you try this:

```
    populationAM = pops['populationEst'][pops['Name'] == 'Amsterdam']
    populationNL = pops['populationEst'][pops['Name'] == 'Netherlands']
```

It will be dtype: Int. But you could easily trnasform it to float.